$\mathbb{R}$-Linear Transformation $T\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ and Lebesgue Measurability
Claim. Given invertible matrix $T\in GL_n(\mathbb{R}),$ then $E\in\mathscr{L}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ if and only if $T(E)\in\mathscr{L}_{\mathbb{R}^n}.$
Note: $\mathscr{L}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ denotes collection of all Lebesgue measurable subsets $\subset\mathbb{R}^n.$
Does anybody have suggestions on how to handle this problem? I'm relatively familiar with Lebesgue measurability in $1$-dimension (when dealing with $\mathbb{R})$ and even 2-dimensional to a certain extent, though I'm far less comfortable dealing with the $(n>2)$-dimensional case (when dealing with $\mathbb{R}^n).$
An approach I'm currently considering is to prove $T(\epsilon)\in\mathscr{L}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ whenever $\epsilon$ is a generator set of $\mathscr{L}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ (i.e., whenever $\epsilon$ denotes $(\mathscr{L}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$-measurable rectangle). Upon showing this, one can then prove that countable union and or intersection of generator sets will also have Lebesgue measurability preserved by linear transformation $T,$ getting us to our desired claim (noting that invertibility of linear transformation $T$ implies converse direction). The main difficulty in this, however, is proving it. I know linear transformations on $\mathscr{L}_{\mathbb{R}}$ act as permutations, though I struggle to figure out an application here.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Edit. Solution comes immediately from fact that (i) $T$ is a homeomorphism ($E\in\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ if and only if $T(E)\in\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$) and (ii) $m(T(E))=\text{det}(T)\cdot m(E)$ (null set $E\in\mathscr{L}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ if and only if null set $T(E)\in\mathscr{L}_{\mathbb{R}^n}).$ Thank you to copper.hat for your suggestion. :)

Since $T$ is a homeomorphism, $E$ is measurable iff $T(E)$ is measurable.

For the purpose of having this question marked as "Answered".
Solution comes immediately from fact that (i) $T$ is a homeomorphism ($E\in\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ if and only if $T(E)\in\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$) and (ii) $m(T(E))=\text{det}(T)\cdot m(E)$ (null set $E\in\mathscr{L}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ if and only if null set $T(E)\in\mathscr{L}_{\mathbb{R}^n}).$
Note that (ii) requires utilizing corollary of regularity theorem which states that $E=K\cup N$ for some compact $K\in\mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ and null set $N\subset\mathbb{R}^n.$ Hence, $m^*(T(E))\leq m(T(K))=\text{det}(T)\cdot m(K)$$\leq\text{det}(T)\cdot m(E)=0,$ and therefore, $T(E)$ is a null set.
Thank you to copper.hat for your comment. It was sufficient in getting me to this solution. :)
